# Probability of given onto Function

Tags: probability

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots , 25\}$. If a student selects a function randomly from the set of all functions from $X$ onto $X$, then what is the probability that the selected function maps
prime numbers to prime numbers?

Comment: Start by figuring out how many prime numbers there are in your set. Also consider the the set {1,2,3,4,5} and try to to work it out for this small set, then generalize.

Comment: @ Sam 
ok I'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: a function from $X$ onto $X$ (where $X$ is a finite set) is a permutation of $X$.  If $A$ and $B$ are the sets of primes and non-primes in $X$, a permutation of $X$ that maps $A$ onto $A$ (and therefore $B$ onto $B$) corresponds to an arbitrary permutation of $A$ and an arbitrary permutation of $B$.  Now, how many are there?